# What is this piece of the window called?

Tags: windows

My window is missing a bit of plastic. I would like to replace it, but do not know what it is called to search for a replacement part.

Here is a picture showing a window that is missing the piece

[image]

Here is a picture showing a window that isn't missing the piece

[image]

The windows are manufactured by Window World.

Comment: You should ask Window World. https://www.windowworld.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entire vertical window frame is called the “jamb”. The portion on the jamb that protrudes outward is called the “stop”.

It appears that this window manufacturer has pre-cut a notch (cutout) in the stop and frame in anticipation of installing a connector for screen, etc. to be applied later.

The piece that seems to be missing is the “cover plate” that covers this pre-cut cutout.

Comment: When you say outward, do you mean inward into the house?

Comment: Outward toward the center of the window, horizontally. The stops retain the sashes.

Comment: Yes, outward means “away” from the jamb or towards the center of the window.

Answer (score 1):

As Lee Sam says, the missing piece is a cover plate for a port in the stops. I suspect it's an installation access area for the sash spring assembly.

I'd cut a new one out of heavy vinyl or plastic and use thin double-sided foam tape to fasten it.